# Problem to run a script inside a function when creating and loading a package in R

Tags: r, r-package

I have created a package in R which can be found [here](https://github.com/paleomariomm/teethR).

In the `R` folder I have this file `preproc.R`, which basically is a function.

In another file, `perikymata_prediction.R` I created another function that needs to run `preproc.R` inside to work properly.

I tried `source("R/preproc.R")` but when using the `perikymata_prediction()` function, `preproc.R` cannot be found.

Can anybody tell me how can I run the script when loading the package and therefore I dont have to run the script inside the function? Is there any other good workaround?

Comment: You do not need to source the file at all. All functions (exported and unexported ones) are available to all funciton wihtin the same package. Looking at your code and seeing some `require` calls, I guess you should (re-) read some [tutorials on how to create a package](https://r-pkgs.org/) as this is typically an anti-pattern. You want ot include it in your namespace and you would only `require` optional packages in help files but not packages which are needed fpr the "normal" execution of your functions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick tip. Now it works nice!